# https redirect just not working IIS, vb.net

Tags: vb.net, https

I am using the following code to try and redirect to https, it is not working. This code has been suggested as the answser for redirects on numerous other posts.

```
If Not Request.IsLocal AndAlso Not Request.IsSecureConnection Then
        Dim redirectUrl As String = Request.Url.ToString().Replace("http:", "https:")
        Response.Redirect(redirectUrl)
 End If
```

Anyone have any ideas on what I can check, using fiddler now to look at traffic.

SSL is set in IIS 6, cert is correctly installed on site.

What else am I missing?

Thanks.,

Comment: What error code do you get?  What does your IIS log state?

Answer (score 0):

If you're testing locally, then your first If condition will be met and it will never go to HTTPS. Anything in the log file if that's not the case? Any error returned on page?

Comment: IsLocal will only be true if I am running the page from within Visual Studio, The page message only says that the URL requires SSL, the usual 402.4 error I think is was.